# How to retain state in View pager Fragment Adapter With Tab?

Tags: android, state

I have total 7 tabs in single screen by using viewpager fragment adapter. in each tab listview is attached and it is prepare by it's own arraylist.(so total 7 arraylist). data arrives in arralist from service. when i change orientation the whole process restart.so how can in gain current state in it?

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following step:

Extend FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.

Check the following link for implementation and more info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Somebody buy this guy a bottle of coke. Thanks Keshav1234.

Comment: @CletusAjibade Thanks a lot :)